# PHP Regex Multiple Instances

Tags: php, regex, csv, preg-match-all, preg-split

I'm currently importing CSV data and need to get it all nice and arrayed out.

Smaller Example Data is as follows.

```
"Name","Address"
"John Doe","5111 Fury Rd
Santa Cruz"
"Jane Doe","321 Tess St Texas"
"Josh Doe","653 1st St 
Orlando Florida
United States"
```

As you can see we need to split on line breaks outside of quotes as str_getcsv isn't multi-line.

I had originally used this expression.

```
$lines = preg_split('/[\r\n]{1,2}(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))/',$data);
```

However preg_split crapped the bed when it was over XXXX amount of characters in the string.

So resorting to preg_match_all currently but need issues with the regex selector.

```
preg_match_all('/^(.*?)[\r\n]{1,2}(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))/', $data, $matches);
```

Currently that matches only the first instance.

```
Array(
    [0] => Array ( [0] => "Name","Address")
    [1] => Array ( [0] => "Name","Address")
)
```

Any clue to get it to return all the data in an array?

Comment: Is this 1 string of data?

Comment: Its CSV data Im importing so it should be 1 giant string separated by line breaks for each entry(row).

Comment: `^` without an `m` modifier only matches the first line (start of the string).

Comment: You're absolutely right. Completely missed that!

Comment: Perhaps `/^"([^"]+?)","([^"]+?)"$/m` would work for you? This also assumes your string would never have escaped quotes in it and that you only have 2 matches

Comment: Checking the quotes until the end with a lookahead isn't the way to go (complicated and inefficient). you need to build a pattern with the `\G` anchor instead.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but I would have done it like this `"((\s|\S)*?)","((\s|\S)*?)"` where `$1` is `name` and `$3` is `address`

Comment: @chris85 your comment was correct. Removing the ^ did return all the results.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does seem that it is running into the same issue as preg_split in that when I try to move through >150 results it craps the bed.

Comment: Does it run out of memory or what happens?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton That arrays everything. ie 50 rows of data returns as 5000. (Theres 100+ data points per row)

Comment: @chris85 AH00051: child pid 18587 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

Comment: Get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in less than a minute or so.

Comment: Maybe I missed something but is this what you are looking for? https://3v4l.org/3Ds55

Comment: PHP error reporting is on?

Comment: Are you importing this CSV data from a file? If so, why not just use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)?

Comment: @chris85 Error reporting is on but the page craps the bed so Thats what im pulling from the error.log files.

Comment: @Andreas Basically my issue but it doesn't work for me. splits the data all weird.

Comment: @DarraghEnright I am not. Grabbing data that would be exported to a csv file but not importing from a file.

Comment: What? In english?`

Comment: @Andreas So the issue is I have 100+ fields per row. My example was just a shortened version. So what that expression does is return two at a time. ie. [0]=>"First Name","Last Name" [1]=>"City","State"... etc

Comment: @user1512593 I saw your comment - deleting my answer as it wasn't relevant, given the underlying errors you are experiencing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to parse it. I have commented out the part that deletes new lines in the address. If you want it just remove the commenting.

```
$re = '/\"(.*?)\",\"(.*?)\"/s';
$data = '"Name","Address"
"John Doe","5111 Fury Rd
Santa Cruz"
"Jane Doe","321 Tess St Texas"
"Josh Doe","653 1st St
Orlando Florida
United States"';

preg_match_all($re, $data, $matches);

/*
foreach($matches[2] as &$value){
    $value = str_replace(PHP_EOL, " ", $value);
}
*/
var_dump($matches);
```

https://3v4l.org/7kRDt

Output with the foreach:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) ""Name","Address""
    [1]=>
    string(36) ""John Doe","5111 Fury Rd
Santa Cruz""
    [2]=>
    string(30) ""Jane Doe","321 Tess St Texas""
    [3]=>
    string(53) ""Josh Doe","653 1st St
Orlando Florida
United States""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Name"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "Jane Doe"
    [3]=>
    string(8) "Josh Doe"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Address"
    [1]=>
    string(23) "5111 Fury Rd Santa Cruz"
    [2]=>
    string(17) "321 Tess St Texas"
    [3]=>
    &string(40) "653 1st St Orlando Florida United States"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Andreas.

Unfortunately, theres 100+ columns of data in each row. This would split the data into pairs. 

 ie. [0]=>"First Name","Last Name" [1]=>"City","State"... etc

Comment: @user1512593 Then just add an appropriate amount of patterns. You can build the pattern with an for loop. `'/\"(.*?)\",\"(.*?)\",\"(.*?)\"/s';` <- is for three columns. Just keep adding the pattern over and over

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was crazy talk repeating the same thing 100+ times but it works great Andreas. Thanks!

Comment: @user1512593 It's not a solution I'm proud of but it if it works... Keep in mind, if one entry does not have the starting or ending " it will fail miserably

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use `preg_match_all()` you could try this pattern to create an array of matches and then map `str_getcsv()` over the results; e.g:

```
<?php

$csvString = <<<CSV
"Name","Address"
"John Doe","5111 Fury Rd
Santa Cruz"
"Jane Doe","321 Tess St Texas"
"Josh Doe","653 1st St
Orlando Florida
United States
CSV;


preg_match_all('/(.*)(?:\n)/m', $csvString, $csvRows);

$csvData = array_map(function ($csvRow) {
    return str_getcsv($csvRow);
}, $csvRows[1]);

print_r($csvData);
```

Given your example input this yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name
            [1] => Address
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => John Doe
            [1] => 5111 Fury Rd
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Santa Cruz"
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jane Doe
            [1] => 321 Tess St Texas
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Josh Doe
            [1] => 653 1st St
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Orlando Florida
        )

)
```

Hope this helps :)